# How to get IMEI for SIM locked iPhone programmatically by using libimobiledevice or any other solution?

Tags: c++, ios, iphone, imei, lockdown

I'm using **libimobiledevice** (C++, Windows, http://www.libimobiledevice.org/) and trying to get iPhone device info. I can obtain **IMEI** for iPhone (without SIM or with unlocked SIM) by using:

- *lockdownd_client_new_with_handshake*

and then

- *lockdown_get_value*

for device with default NULL domain and enumerating all keys (or just by getting correct plist with key "**InternationalMobileEquipmentIdentity**")

but I can't get exactly this one value if iPhone is SIM locked. I mean the phone with "**SIMStatus**" = "**kCTSIMSupportSIMStatusPINLocked**". There is no such key returned by lockdown. I'm looking for advice [or explanation] how I can get IMEI in that case. I think, it is possible. But how? Why it ain't returning for SIM locked iPhone?..

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: did you try with ideviceinfo cmd